# How can I compare a variable to see if it is null in SQL Server Transact SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to check if the variable `@Test` is null. I tried (`@Test = null`) but there's a syntax error.

How can I check for this? I notice there is something called `IsNull` but I am not sure how to use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

`@Test IS NULL`

So, e.g. as a predicate in a `WHERE` clause:

`WHERE (@Test IS NULL) OR ...`

or in an `IF` statement inside a stored procedure:

```
IF (@Test IS NULL) AND ( ... some other predicate )
BEGIN
 ...
END
```

Comment: So I should do ( @Test IS NULL ) ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
if (@test is null)
begin
<True block statements>
end
```

Answer (score 1):

use `@Test IS NULL`
DESCRIPTION

The SQL IS NULL condition is used to test for a NULL value in a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement.

> SYNTAX

The syntax for the SQL IS `NULL` condition is:

```
expression IS NULL
```

Parameters or Arguments

expression is the value to test.

> **NOTE**
>
> If expression is a NULL value, the condition evaluates to TRUE.
>   If expression is not a NULL value, the condition evaluates to FALSE.

for more information :

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/is_null.php

Example :

```
Select * from MyTable where @Test IS NULL
```

if you want to check @Test should not be NULL then you can use

```
Select * from MyTable where @Test IS NOT NULL
```

information About `ISNULL()`

`ISNULL ()` Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.
ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )

```
SELECT ISNULL(@Test,'True')
```